Barcode scanner enter value issue on Zebra Android phone
When you scan a barcode in the first entry in the Maui app running on the Zebra TC21, an Enter key is added and the focus moves to the second entry. When you scan a barcode in the second entry, the app compares the values ​​of the first and second entries and outputs different sounds, but it does not recognize the enter key at the second entry. However, when I press the physical Enter key on Android phone, it is recognized and a sound is played. please help me.
When you scan a barcode on the Zebra tc21, the enter key is passed properly, so the focus moves to entrySecond normally. Why does entrySecond not recognize the barcode scanner's enter key, but only the physical keyboard's enter key?

How do you determine that the enter key is pressed?

I binded "ReturnCommand" in entrySecond

So you have two identical entries, both of them have bound return command, one of them works, the other does not?
Second question, can you check how the keyboards look (The "send" button, when you manually open the soft keyboard).
A wild stab in the dark, if you see any difference, would be this : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/android/platform-specifics/entry-ime-options?view=net-maui-8.0

Just one last question, are you sure that the scanner setting is set to "enter" and not to "tab"? It is very common for them to send "tab" at the end, not "enter". Double check this.


Yes, i have two identifical entries, first is work but second is not work. 2. As your guide i can changed two types keyboard enter key. Now i am testing two types enter key.


Hi, I am sure scanner set "enter" and not "tab", and  in code behind file at entryFirst.Completed event, i coded DisplayAlert, then barcode data with "enter" it should Display message, but not work. only software keyboard "enter" fire DisplayAlert.

I will post something, I have tested it like 5 minutes ago. Do you see any difference between the code I have, and your code?

Thanks very much, actually i coded barcode scanning app in vs2019 4 years ago.(https://github.com/David1930/IsSame/blob/master/IsSame/MainPage.xaml.cs). now i am trying to change to vs2022 with mvvm. but code is not working barcode added enter key. it only work software keyboard enter key. i am afraid this error was caused that issue(https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/13921). i post my code below. please help. anyway now i am coding without mvvm. but still same error.

Hi, I solve it. Thank for your help. I got alot information from you. Problem was not code. it was Zebra TC21's setting. Zebra use "DataWedge" for barcode scanner setting. and setting should be below.
Action key character --> Line feed, Send data --> check, Send ENTER key --> check.
I did not set Action key character. 4 years ago i developed same app. at that time i used VS2019 and used xamarin forms. now i am using MAUI. i think environment of developmnet cause this issue. thank you for your kindness. good luck for you.

This is demo code for your problem:
public partial class MainViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [RelayCommand]
    public async Task Done()
    {
        await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Done","Done","Done");
    }

    [RelayCommand]
    public async Task Done2()
    {
        await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Done2", "Done2", "Done2");
    }
}

And in the XAML:
<ScrollView>
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Entry WidthRequest="100"
               ReturnCommand="{Binding DoneCommand}"/>
        <Entry WidthRequest="100"
               ReturnCommand="{Binding Done2Command}"/>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ScrollView>

This is enough, that after scan the focus will move from the first, to the second entry, and the alerts will be displayed after good read.
Of course, I do not have EXACTLY this zebra model, but I have mobile device with barcode scanner, that is setup to format [LF] after the read value (Line feed).

Thank you very much. your kindness. actually i write barcode app 4 years ago with VS2019(https://github.com/David1930/IsSame). it works well. this app working simply. through two entry, barcode scan, then two entry is same then play ding dong deng~. not same then fault sound play. this app is working on Zebra. my code is here. https://github.com/David1930/IsSame. now i am changing code with mvvm in VS2022. i post vs2022 code below. problem is never playing sound with barcode. I compiled same zebra android phone. old app is still working. but new app never playing.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
             xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:isSame2023.ViewModels"
             xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maui.Controls.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Microsoft.Maui.Controls"
             x:DataType="viewmodels:BarcodeViewModel"
             x:Class="isSame2023.Views.ScanPage"
             Title="ScanPage">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <viewmodels:BarcodeViewModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <ContentPage.Padding>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
            <On Platform="iOS" Value="0,50,0,0"/>
            <On Platform="Android" Value="2,2,2,2"/>
        </OnPlatform>
    </ContentPage.Padding>

    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Frame BackgroundColor="#2196F3" Padding="20" CornerRadius="0">
            <Label Style="{StaticResource LargeLabel}"  Text="Safe Combine Ver 1.0" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="White" FontSize="30" />
        </Frame>

        <toolkit:MediaElement
                x:Name="mediaElement"
                >
        </toolkit:MediaElement>

        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>  <!-- 0 -->
                <RowDefinition Height="10"/>    <!-- 1 -->
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>  <!-- 2 -->
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>  <!-- 3 -->
                <RowDefinition Height="10"/>    <!-- 4 -->
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>  <!-- 5 -->
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>  <!-- 6 -->
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>  <!-- 7 -->
                <RowDefinition Height="10"/>    <!-- 8 -->
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>  <!-- 9 -->
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="270"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Label Style="{StaticResource MediumLabel}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                    Text="Tick! Tick! Tick!" HorizontalOptions="Center"
                    FontSize="Body"/>
            <Label Style="{StaticResource SmallLabel}"  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Text="1st Scaned Value:" HorizontalOptions="End"/>
            <Label Style="{StaticResource SmallLabel}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding FirstScan}"/>
            
            <Label Style="{StaticResource SmallLabel}" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Text="2nd Scaned Value:" HorizontalOptions="End"/>
            <Label Style="{StaticResource SmallLabel}" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding SecondScan}"/>

            <Label Style="{StaticResource SmallLabel}" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" Text="1st Scan:" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="End"/>
            
            <Entry android:Entry.ImeOptions="Default" Style="{StaticResource SmallEntry}" x:Name="entryFirst" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" Placeholder="Please 1st Scan" 
                   Text="{Binding FirstScan}" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
            
            <Label Style="{StaticResource SmallLabel}" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="0" Text="2nd Scan:" HorizontalOptions="End"/>
            
            <Entry android:Entry.ImeOptions="Default" Style="{StaticResource SmallEntry}" x:Name="entrySecond" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="1" Placeholder="Please 2nd Scan" 
                   Text="{Binding SecondScan}" ReturnCommand="{Binding PlaySoundCommand}"/>

            <Button x:Name="BtnInitialize" Grid.Row="9" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="Initialize" Clicked="BtnInitialize_Clicked"/>
        </Grid>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>


using MvvmHelpers;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace isSame2023.ViewModels
{
    public class BarcodeViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        private string? firstScan, secondScan, resultSound;

        public ICommand PlaySoundCommand { get; }
        
        public event EventHandler<string>? SoundSourceChanged;

        public BarcodeViewModel()
        {
            PlaySoundCommand = new MvvmHelpers.Commands.Command(PlaySoundBasedOnComparision);
        }

        private void PlaySoundBasedOnComparision()
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstScan) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(secondScan))
            {
                return;
            }

            string? selectedSoundSource = GetSoundSourceByKey(firstScan, secondScan);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedSoundSource))
            {
                PlaySound(selectedSoundSource);
            }
        }

        private void PlaySound(string source)
        {
            SoundSourceChanged?.Invoke(this, source);
        }

        private string? GetSoundSourceByKey(string firstKey, string secondKey)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstKey) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(secondKey))
                return null;

            //RO Number 11 digit
            if (firstKey.Length == 11 && secondKey.Length == 11)
            {
                if (firstKey.Substring(0, 9) == secondKey.Substring(0, 9))
                    return "PASS3.mp3";
                else
                    return "ERROR1.mp3";
            }
            else if (firstKey == secondKey)
                return "PASS3.mp3";
            else
                return "NO.mp3";
        }

        public string? FirstScan
        {
            get => firstScan;
            //Refractored.MvvmHelpers, OneNote Xamarin&Xamarin.Forms for Beginner 7.2
            set => SetProperty(ref firstScan, value);
        }

        public string? SecondScan
        {
            get => secondScan;
            set => SetProperty(ref secondScan, value);
        }

        public string? ResultSound
        {
            get => resultSound;
            set => SetProperty(ref resultSound, value);
        }
    }
}

